# WINAPI GetKeyboardState behavior modified by GetKeyState when application is out of focus?

Tags: winapi, keyboard, focus, hook, keyboard-events

When calling the WINAPI command `GetKeyboardState(aByteArray)` from a WPF application (and assumedly other applications as well), holding down the `SHIFT` key is correctly detected only when the application has focus. When the application does not have focus, `aByteArray[VK_SHIFT]` is `0` after the method call.

However, if `GetKeyState(aVKCode)` is called immediately prior to `GetKeyboardState(aByteArray),` for any value of `aVKCode`, even if the return value is discarded, then `GetKeyboardState(aByteArray)` will provide the correct non-zero state of the held `SHIFT` key when the application is not in focus.

This behavior is counterintuitive and appears to have caused many programmers grief. I believe that there is relevant information in the documentation for `GetKeyboardState` which reads:

> The status changes as a thread removes keyboard messages from its message queue. The status does not change as keyboard messages are posted to the thread's message queue, nor does it change as keyboard messages are posted to or retrieved from message queues of other threads.

Potentially, `GetKeyState()` interacts with the message queue in such a way that it must be called prior to `GetKeyboardState()` in order for `GetKeyboardState()` to behave as desired. However, I am unfamiliar with the concept of the message queue and how items are added and removed by Windows, and so I thought I'd ask here. Can anyone explain why a call to `GetKeyboardState()` alone cannot capture the `SHIFT` key being held without application focus?

Comment: (Keyboard) input is virtualized per thread (or group of input-attached threads). Each thread maintains its own keyboard state information. Pressing a key while a window owned by a thread has input focus will not update the keyboard state in any other thread (except for those that are attached to this thread). More details at [Asynchronous input vs synchronous input, a quick introduction](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20130604-00/?p=4173).

Comment: Here is an updated link: [Asynchronous input vs synchronous input, a quick introduction](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20130604-00/?p=4173)

Answer (score 3):

[GetKeyState](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/windows/desktop/ms646299(v=vs.85).aspx) is always associated to the last processed message of a thread. So when you use `GetKeyState` inside a message handler you get the keystate when this message was placed into the message queue.

If message processing is delayed, this guarantees, that each message can be processed by the programmer and he can detect the key states in that moment. I.E.: "Was the Shift key down when the mouse click happened?"

Just using `GetKeyState` may skip a state or message if other messages were processed in between.

To detect the *current* key state you must use [GetAsyncKeyState](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/windows/desktop/ms646293(v=vs.85).aspx)

The functions are well documented.

Finally: Neither GetKeyState nor GetAsyncKeyState is a good way to detect if the shift key was pressed inside a program. Process messages and detect WM_KEYDOWN.

Comment: Thanks for the information. The code that I am looking at uses WM_KEYDOWN to detect keypresses, and if the key from that message is alphanumeric, then I use GetKeyState to find if shift or capslock was down so that they key indicated by WM_KEYDOWN can be converted to ASCII. 

Therefore, I do want the behavior described in your first two paragraphs. The reason that I chose to use GetKeyState is that the shift and/or caps lock keys may be pressed before I begin processing WM_KEYDOWN messages, and I still want to be able to detect those cases.

In this scenario, which method would you use?